# Open cv - Processing - detect grapes

Tags: opencv, processing

I have a problem with opencv, I must detect and tracking grapes with a camera using the program: processing, how do it do? Can I have an exemple? thankyou

This code is an exemple code that detect the face:

```java
import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.*;

Capture video;
OpenCV opencv;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  video = new Capture(this, 640/2, 480/2);
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, 640/2, 480/2);
  opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);  

  video.start();
}

void draw() {
  scale(2);
  opencv.loadImage(video);

  image(video, 0, 0 );

  noFill();
  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  strokeWeight(3);
  Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect();
  println(faces.length);

  for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    println(faces[i].x + "," + faces[i].y);
    rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
  }
}

void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  c.read();
}
```

Comment: Not your personal coding army. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I update the post

Comment: Mind posting short clip of the balls ? :)

Comment: this program capture a video in direct, and it must detect some circles (I wont use it for detect graps )

Comment: did you mean grapes ?

Comment: yes,I have correct the mistake

Answer (score 3):

The code you're using trying to detect faces.

As a basic breakdown you will need to segment the object you're trying to detect (grapes in this case) from the background. I recommend starting simple:

1. try simply using [threshold()](http://atduskgreg.github.io/opencv-processing/reference/gab/opencv/OpenCV.html#threshold(int)) and see if the highlights of each grape can be isolated. Hopefully they'll be the brightest spot in the image (if the camera isn't looking directly at a light source)
2. if method 1 isn't effective, try using colour detection: if you what kind of grapes you want to detect you can select a range of colours to detect and ignore the rest. Run the [HSVColorTracking](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/tree/master/examples/HSVColorTracking) example and have a play with the ranges. Swap the marbles image with an image of grapes and see what you can get.
3. OpenCV has a function specifically built for detecting circles: [HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#HoughCircles(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20double,%20double)). Unfortunately Greg's OpenCV Processing library doesn't wrap this function as he does with [HoughLines](http://atduskgreg.github.io/opencv-processing/reference/gab/opencv/OpenCV.html#findLines(int,%20double,%20double)) yet, but there it provides function to convert between OpenCV's `Mat` and Processing `PImage`. If you're just getting started with Processing and don't have a experience with plain Java, this may be more convoluted.

Try basic thresholding and HSB range thresholding first. Once you have a good looking binary image (where the background is completely black and the grapes are white) you can [findContours](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/tree/master/examples/FindContours), get the centroid of each contour, compute the [minEnclosingCircle()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#minEnclosingCircle(org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20org.opencv.core.Point,%20float[])), etc.

Another option might be to train a support vector machine to distinguish between two classes: grapes and not grapes. This is a more advanced topic, but luckily Greg Borenstein, author of the OpenCV Processing library wrote a nice article with videos and example code on creating on the topic. Check out [PSVM: Support Vector Machines for Processing](http://makematics.com/code/psvm/).

Here's a mashup of the [HueRangeSelection](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/blob/master/examples/HueRangeSelection/HueRangeSelection.pde) and [FindContours](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/blob/master/examples/FindContours/FindContours.pde) examples using an google image result:

[image: grape-harvest-inside.jpg]

```
import gab.opencv.*;

PImage img;
OpenCV opencv;
Histogram histogram;

int lowerb = 50;
int upperb = 100;

ArrayList<Contour> contours;
ArrayList<Contour> polygons;


void setup() {
  size(800,400);
  img = loadImage("grape-harvest-inside.jpg");
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, img);
  opencv.useColor(HSB);
}

void draw() {
  opencv.loadImage(img);

  image(img, 0, 0);  

  opencv.setGray(opencv.getH().clone());
  opencv.inRange(lowerb, upperb);
  histogram = opencv.findHistogram(opencv.getH(), 255);

  image(opencv.getOutput(), width/2, height/2, width/2,height/2);

  noStroke(); fill(0);
  histogram.draw(10, height - 230, 400, 200);
  noFill(); stroke(0);
  line(10, height-30, 410, height-30);

  text("Hue", 10, height - (textAscent() + textDescent()));

  float lb = map(lowerb, 0, 255, 0, 400);
  float ub = map(upperb, 0, 255, 0, 400);

  stroke(255, 0, 0); fill(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  line(lb + 10, height-30, ub +10, height-30);
  ellipse(lb+10, height-30, 3, 3 );
  text(lowerb, lb-10, height-15);
  ellipse(ub+10, height-30, 3, 3 );
  text(upperb, ub+10, height-15);

  contours = opencv.findContours();
  for (Contour contour : contours) {
    stroke(0, 255, 0);
    noFill();
    contour.draw();
  }
}

void mouseMoved() {
  if (keyPressed) {
    upperb += mouseX - pmouseX;
  } 
  else {
    if (upperb < 255 || (mouseX - pmouseX) < 0) {
      lowerb += mouseX - pmouseX;
    }

    if (lowerb > 0 || (mouseX - pmouseX) > 0) {
      upperb += mouseX - pmouseX;
    }
  }

  upperb = constrain(upperb, lowerb, 255);
  lowerb = constrain(lowerb, 0, upperb-1);
}
```

Here's a preview of selecting range closer to the grapes colour:

[image: HSB Colour Range Selection]

You already notice this is both easy to use, but also not full proof and should get you on the right track to asking yourself the right kind of questions.
For example:

- what environments are you supporting ? (indoors/outdoors, natural lighting, artificial lighting, daytime, nighttime, both ? etc.) - light controls what your input images will look like and is therefore crucial
- how many different grapes will you support ? (can you get away with a single type (colour range), are there are elements that may trigger a false positive ?)
- etc.

Comment: Sorry, I can't to detect the form can you do the code please?

Comment: Have you tried using the [HSVColorTracking](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/blob/master/examples/HSVColorTracking/HSVColorTracking.pde) example swapping the image of marbles with grapes ? What output did you get ?

Comment: yes, it detect, but I wont that detect also the form, can you do, I don't understand how do it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the form. The outline of each grape ? The outline of a cluster of grapes ? Any way you could visualise this so it's easier for others to understand ?

Comment: Samuele means bunch of grapes, many small circles. I'm a friend of Samuele. Thanks for the interesting feedback

Comment: We are trying to find the grapes to build a robot